# What equipment can I used to dig a foundation very close to another structure?

Tags: foundation

I only have 7' between houses to get a backhoe/trench digger in to dig a house foundation. Any suggestions on a machine to use?

Comment: This is very site specific. A power shovel (not so popular nowadays), power backhoe, or bulldozer is the preferred tool, but a hog-loader (front-end loader), tractor backhoe, or a skid-steer loader can be used where space is limited. Can you post a diagram or plat map of the site?

Comment: How deep do you need to dig? Mini-excavators have a limited depth compared to a normal back hoe.

Answer (score 2):

So called 'mini-diggers' (as they are often called in the UK) now go down to a size which will easily fit through a 900mm doorway. Your situation isn't an impossibly tight dig. I'd recommend simply visiting your local tool/digger hire centre and hiring the largest machine you can get into the space you have. Don't forget you'll need room to turn the boom around at least 180 degrees. Possibly a micro, micro-plus or mini.

NOTE: Terminology will vary from country to country depending on what excavator manufactures are present.

Comment: We call them mini-excavators in the northern USA.

Comment: Same in the UK, although a little more 'technical' description than the more colloquially used 'mini-digger'...